# Langchain conversational Agent

Tags: python, openai-api, py-langchain

I was building a chatbot using `CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` agent in Langchain how can I make it to use multiple tools. Is there a way to customize the final output? I am using OpenAI's GPT 4 model.And also I'm using Zep as the long-term memory

```
agent_executor = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True, memory=memory)
```